# How to find a required file and read it in a zip file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I have zip files and each zip file contains three subfolders (i.e. ini, log, and output). I want to read a file from output folder and it contains three csv files with different names. Suppose three files name are: `initial.csv`, `intermediate.csv`, and `final.csv`. and just want to read `final.csv` file.

The code that I tried to read file is:

```
import zipfile
import numpy
import pandas as pd

zipfiles = glob.glob('/home/data/*.zip')
for i in np.arange(len(zipfiles)):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zpfiles[i])
    f = zip.open(zip.namelist().startswith('final'))
    data = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[3,7])
```

and the error I got is `'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

How can I find the correct file and read it?

Comment: change your `glob` call ? `zipfiles = glob.glob('/home/data/*final*.zip')`

Comment: @Umar.H, it gives empty list :(

Comment: then I assume your path is incorrect or that file does not exist in that location.

Comment: I double checked. the path is correct. May be I want to make it clear that, final.csv is in subdirectory 'output'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replase

```
f = zip.open(zip.namelist().startswith('final'))
```

With

```
f = zip.open('output/final.csv')
```

If you can "find" it:

```
filename = ([name for name in zip.namelist() if name.startswith('output/final')][0])
f = zip.open(filename)
```

Comment: Edited with output/ folder.

Answer (score 2):

To find sub dirs, let's switch to pathlib which uses `glob`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile
import pandas as pd


dfs = []

files = Path('/home/data/').rglob('*final*.zip') #rglob recursively trawls all child dirs.
for file in files:
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zpfiles[file])
    ....
    # your stuff
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[3,7])
    dfs.append(df)
```